# Disable keyboard on linux

Tags: linux, keyboard, system

I would like to be able to disable the keyboard only on certains usb ports (when you press a key, nothing happens). I already find xinput but is it possible to automatize the processus to find the  of the keyboard in order to do automatically :

```
xinput float <id>
```

?

I also try to use ioctl() whithout success. Indeed, it works when I try it without Xorg (X server) is loading. Seems it's not working when Xorg is load.

I also try to use rmmod without sucess.

Any ideas, suggestions will be appreciate.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried just unplugging the keyboard?

Comment: @beauXjames ^^ this is not my goal. The goal is even if you plug the keyboard you can't use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I find the answer of my problem, I simply modified the source of the linux usb driver used by my keyboard. Indeed, I juste disable the irq on certains USB ports. You can find more infos [here](http://spher-os.com/index.php/2015/07/07/disable-the-mouse-and-keyboard-entries-on-usb/) if you are interest.